# Why did Danny get shot at the end of American History X?

Tags: american-history-x

How did the 'smoke in the face' incident lead to Danny getting shot? Is this really grounds to kill someone?

Comment: Blowing smoke in someone's face has a couple meanings. If you've never encountered them, this can seem weird. I think this is clear enough of a question to be be valid. Especially considering that one definition is "I want to have sex with you" and the other is an insult or provocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blowing smoke into someone's face is an insult. It means you do not respect them, nor their space (which can mean territory). Consider the deaths of people who inadvertently wore the wrong color(s) in a gang territory.

In some gang-member's minds, it does not take much to warrant injuring or even killing someone. Protecting *your* integrity and the integrity of *any others* you represent is the definition of being a **member**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Danny was shot as revenge for the murder his brother, Derek, committed when he curb stomped that guy. The shooter was the dead guy's younger brother.